# Como gravar um arquivo em ISO-8859-1 sem perder a acentuação

Tags: java, codificação-de-caracteres

Gostaria de saber por favor como grava um arquivo em `ISO-8859-1` e não perder a acentuação gráfica se possível, minha duvida vem do seguinte. Ao definir no Eclipse que a codificação do arquivo segue este charset que citei acima, ele salva corretamente os arquivos usando acento mas se eu via código Java tentar realizar uma edição de arquivo e salvar neste charset, irei perder os acentos. O que fazer?

```
public class Diretorio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream;

        try {

            List<File> listFile = getFileList("C:\\Users\\Diego Macario\\Documents\\Eclipse\\ecred_manat\\WebContent");
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\teste.properties");
            properties.load(inputStream);


            for (File file : listFile) {

                List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

                for (Entry<Object, Object> label : properties.entrySet()) {

                    String key = "#{lbl['" + (String) label.getKey() + "']}";

                    for (String string : lines) {

                        if (string.contains(key)) {

                            int index = lines.indexOf(string);

                            String value = (String) label.getValue();
                            value = new String(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            string = string.replace(key, value);
                            lines.set(index, string);

                        }
                    }

                }

                Files.write(file.toPath(), lines, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"), StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static List<File> getFileList(String path) {
        String[] extension = { "xhtml" };
        List<File> listFile = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.listFiles(
                new File(path), extension, true));
        return listFile;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ao **ler** o arquivo via código Java, você está usando o charset correto? Se você salva no Eclipse (ou de qualquer outro jeito) um arquivo em `ISO-8859-1`, então esse arquivo pode sim ser lido perfeitamente por um programa Java (que, se feito da forma correta, armazenará seu conteúdo numa `String` `UTF-16` sem perdas), manipulado, e salvo novamente na mesma codificação. Se está tendo problemas em fazê-lo, favor postar o código utilizado (somente o trecho relevante).

Comment: @mgibsonbr coloquei o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar a classe java.nio.charset.Charset quando construir um objeto [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Com isso você está garantindo que está construindo um objeto na mesma codificação que você especificou no Eclipse. No seu caso use o nome "ISO-8859-1" e o método estático  `forName` que te fornece um objeto Charset para usar na String.